# Setting zoom level from table attributes using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zoom

Is there anyway to set the zoom level after double-clicking on black arrow in table attributes?

It seems to default to 1:4,000. As I'm checking over hundreds of areas and it would be nice to be able to automatically zoom in (around 1:600) to each item  on the table without having to scroll the mouse wheel each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. that "double-click" is taking you to the extent of the feature you clicked on (the feature for that row). It is the same as choosing "Zoom To" in the context menu shown below. You can set the scale after you get there or better yet, you can start from a given scale and simply right click the row and choose "Pan To" from this context menu (accessed by right-clicking the **row** aka "the black arrow").

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Zooming to your desired level and using the Pan To option is your best bet (as per [the previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198354/115)).

A handy hint is that you can hold control and double click the row indicator to quickly Pan To (rather than the default zoom to).